# Magento not creating images in 2nd store

Tags: image, multistore

I've just added a 2nd store to my Magento installation. Any new product that is uploaded to the backend only displays in the primary store and not in the 2nd one - While images for products that were created before the 2nd store was enabled display perfectly in both stores.

Magento is calling the placeholder image url in the 2nd store, which suggests that the images aren't being created. I have created symlinks between the two directories and the files are part of the www-data group.

Comment: `I have created symlinks between the two directories` which two directories?

Comment: How have you implemented your multi store configuration exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Images and products need to be allocated to each store.

Products: Click edit and selected "Websites"... make sure all applicable websites are checked.

Images: Make sure that the images are selected (if the above wasn't done before, you'll see new options about where they'll be shown).  Another thing is, if your new store setup is http://existingshopdomain.com/newstore or similar, you'll need to change the media url to point to the existing store's media folder (if it's a different domain pointing to the same directories it will be fine. e.g. http://newshopdomain.com).